# Word Problem Related to Quadratic Equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The product of the ages of a father and his son is $180$ years. When the son becomes as old as his father is now, the sum of their ages will be $84$ years. Find their present ages.

My Attempt:

Let the present age of father be $x$ years and the present age of son be $y$ years.

According to question,

$x\times y= 180$

$y=\frac {180}{x}$.

But how should I get the other equation?

Comment: Suppose the father's age is $y$ and the son's age is $x$. When the son becomes as old as his father is now, the time that will have passed, will be $y-x$ years. So after $y-x$ years, the son is $y$ years old and the father is $2y-x$ years old. Can you do it from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The son then has to be $x $ years of age. The time elapsed for this to take place is $x-y $ years. So the father should be of age $x+(x-y)=2x-y $ years. Thus we have, $$ \text {Father's age} +\text {Son's age} =84$$ $$\Rightarrow (2x-y)+(x)= 84 \tag {2} $$ Hope you can take it from here.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  how many years does it take the son to reach his father's current age (depending on $x,y$)?  The son is then $x$ years old.  How old is the father at that time?  Now use the sentence about $84$.

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ is father's current age. Since the years passed would be $x-y$ for the age of son to reach his father's age, then son's age will be $x$ and age of father will be $x+(x-y)=2x-y$

Therefore,

$$3x-y=84$$